# Can I vectorize this Python Pandas code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, vectorization

I am trying to make a function that takes a dataframe as an argument and returns a list of stock price jumps that meet a threshold, y, over a lookahead period, x. I want to put these observations into another dataframe (right now, I'm just putting each stock price 'jump' into a list of lists), but I am unable to run this code within a reasonable amount of time since the dataframe I'm working with is 4000columnsx3000rows. Is there a way to vectorize these for loops to speed up the program? Thanks.

```
def jumpFilter(df, y=.1,x=1):
    lastPrice=1000 #initialization
    listOfJumps=[] #ticker, date, jump threshold passed, lookahead period, pos/neg, percentJump, avgdailyrateofchange, counter
    y=.2 #threshold-percent change in stock price
    x=1 #lookahead period
    for i in range(1,len(df.columns)):
        counter=0 #counts how many days of consistent jumps have been occurring
        for j in range(len(df.values[:])):
            if (j+x)<len(df.values):
                if type(df.values[j][i])!=str:
                    if math.isnan(float(df.values[j][i]))==False:
                        if df.values[j][i]!=0:
                            currentPrice=df.values[j][i]
                            futurePrice=df.values[j+x][i]
                            if futurePrice>currentPrice:
                                posneg=1
                            elif futurePrice<currentPrice:
                                posneg=0
                            percentJump=abs((currentPrice-futurePrice)/currentPrice)
                            if (currentPrice-futurePrice)/currentPrice>=y:
                                counter+=1
                                avgDailyRateChange=percentJump/(x+counter-1)
                            elif (currentPrice-futurePrice)/currentPrice<y and counter>=1:
                                listOfJumps.append([df.columns[i],df.values[j][0], y, x, posneg, percentJump, avgDailyRateChange, counter])
                                counter=0
    return listOfJumps
```

Comment: Questions about improvements to working code are best done on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh thank you, sorry, I thought this was the right place.

Comment: No worries, I am looking forward to seeing your code on code review.  I suggest you post a small working data set and the expected results with at least two columns and 30-40 rows with the review.  Best if this data is cut and paste-able python code.

Comment: @RobertGrote There's some overlap. But in general, SO is for *highly specific* programming problems, whereas CR is for general reviews.

Comment: Thanks, we actually just solved it through some intense Googling!

Comment: `vectorize` in `pandas` and `numpy` generally refers to a specific programming strategy.  It's not asking for 'general review'.  Look at all the 'vectorize' items there are in the `Related` sidebar.